# Disable SMTP on Windows SBS 2011

Tags: smtp, windows-sbs-2011

I have a server running Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard.  I have disabled the SMTP service, removed the Web Server Role, and blocked port 25 in Windows Firewall.  Why am I still able to connect via telnet and send mail along with everyone else on the planet?

Comment: Exchange server 2010 (which is the version of Exchange in SBS 2011) doesn't use the SMTP service. It uses the Microsoft Exchange Transport service.

Comment: @joeqwerty Disabling Exchange Transport Service worked.  If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange server 2010 (which is the version of Exchange in SBS 2011) doesn't use the SMTP service. It uses the Microsoft Exchange Transport service. Disable that service and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is a remote access technology.  Essentially, you telnet to port 23 on a server and get a remote cmd line.

Telnet is advertised on port 23.  Port 25, as you are aware, is smtp for mail which is a different service.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP means that he used telnet to connect to port 25, which is a fairly standard way of testing SMTP communications.

Comment: gotcha, I am sometimes a skimmer.  here is the proof.